# Sum multiple files into 1 output file

Tags: bash, awk

Hoping someone woll be able to point me in the right direction. I am new to bash scripting and I believe awk should be able to solve this problem.

I have multiple files that I want to process, the data located in **$1** will always stay the same, the separator is just a space and numbers in **$2** will change.

I wish to sum $2 from the multiple files and output to a new file. Example below:

**File1.txt**

```
DATA:TEST0 20
DATA:TEST1 4
DATA:TEST2 39
DATA:TEST3 11
```

**File2.txt**

```
DATA:TEST0 2
DATA:TEST1 0
DATA:TEST2 26
DATA:TEST3 9
```

**File3.txt**

```
DATA:TEST0 44
DATA:TEST1 16
DATA:TEST2 21
DATA:TEST3 7
```

**Output.txt** is the output I wish to achieve from the above files

```
DATA:TEST0 66
DATA:TEST1 20
DATA:TEST2 86
DATA:TEST3 27
```

I have tried the following but it does not work

`paste file* | awk '{$2=$1+$2}1' | tee output.txt`

Any advice would be appreicated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `$1 + $2`? `$1` is a name like `DATA:TEST0`, it doesn't make sense to add it.

Comment: run `paste file*` by itself to see what your input to `awk` is going to look like; I'm guessing what you probably had in mind was `join` (though that would be a bit involved since limited to working on 2 files at a time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paste` puts the files side by side, you don't need that. Just give all the filenames as arguments to `awk` and it will process them sequentially.

Use an associative array for the sums for each keyword in column 1.

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' file* | tee output.txt
```

To keep the original order in the files, you can go back to using `paste`. Then you have to loop every other column, adding to a sum variable.

```
paste file* | awk '{sum=0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i+=2) sum += $i; print($1, sum)' | tee output.txt
```

Comment: Works great, thanks for your solution. Is there a simple way to explicitly keep the order without using the sort command?

Comment: I've added how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk`:

```bash
awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
for (i in sums) print i, sums[i]}' File{1..3}.txt

DATA:TEST0 66
DATA:TEST1 20
DATA:TEST2 86
DATA:TEST3 27
```

Note that `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` is used merely for sorting the output in numerical order of the array index i.e. `$1`. If that's not desired then following `awk` would work for any awk version:

```bash
awk '{sums[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sums) print i,sums[i]}' File{1..3}.txt
```

---

To maintain original order use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '!($1 in sums) {seq[++n] = $1} {sums[$1] += $2; }
END {for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print seq[i], sums[seq[i]]}' File{1..3}.txt

DATA:TEST0 66
DATA:TEST1 20
DATA:TEST2 86
DATA:TEST3 27
```

Comment: This also works great! Thanks for your suggestion. Is there a way of keeping the original order?

Comment: I have updated answer to that maintains original order of keys

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '
     {a[$1]+=$2}
     END{ 
        asorti(a,b); for(i in b) print b[i],a[b[i]]
     }
 ' File[123].txt

DATA:TEST0 66
DATA:TEST1 20
DATA:TEST2 86
DATA:TEST3 27
```

Comment: That would be orders of magnitude slower than any of the answers that use awk, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: There's just no reason to do it in bash though and I don't think it's obvious to a newcomer that that's the case and how vastly faster an awk solution would be so it's worth referring them to that article.

Answer (score 1):

AWK can do that task as already shown, but if you are allowed to use other tools I suggest trying [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), in that case it should be sufficient to do

```
cat File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt | datamash groupby 1 sum 2
```